# Error loading IPython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Once I opened a notebook file with Jupyter (it asks me to convert the file) I never can open it in the standard IPython notebook anymore. I get the following error:

```
Error loading notebook
Bad Request

2014-12-21 04:13:03.203 [NotebookApp] WARNING | Unreadable Notebook: /FunIT experiment.ipynb global name  'NBFormatError' is not defined
WARNING:tornado.access:400 GET /api/notebooks/FunIT%20experiment.ipynb?_=1419153182928 (::1) 3.11ms referer=http://localhost:8888/notebooks/FunIT%20experiment.ipynb
```

An example of such corrupted files is this one:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7io99wpoivxmc8f/FunIT%20experiment.ipynb?dl=0

How can I revert this process? I need to open these files with the standard IPython notebook (v2.2.0).

Comment: Which version of IPython are you using?

Comment: I am using IPython 2.2.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem has to do with incompatibility of the notebook and your IPython version. In my current version of IPython:

```
ipython --version 
2.3.1
```

When I try to open the file (FunIT\ experiment.ipynb):

```
ipython notebook FunIT\ experiment.ipynb
```

I get the following error message

> **Error loading notebook**
>
> Unreadable Notebook: FunIT experiment.ipynb Unsupported nbformat
>   version 4

The error message indicates that the notebook format is not supported. Let's install the development version, https://github.com/ipython/ipython. I used virtual Environment, http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/, but it's not necessary.

## Install virtual environment

```
pip install virtualenv
mkdir test
cd test
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

## Ipython Notebook development installation

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/ipython/ipython.git
cd ipython
pip install -e ".[notebook]" --user
```

Now I have the current development version.

```
ipython --version
3.0.0-dev
```

And I can open the file with ipython notebook

```
ipython notebook FunIT\ experiment.ipynb
```

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas.tools.pivot import pivot_table
#from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%pylab inline
#from sklearn.neighbors.kde import KernelDensity
import seaborn as sns
import scipy.stats as st
sns.set()
```

Answer (score 11):

Upgrading IPython fixed it for me:

`pip install ipython --upgrade`

Comment: I found an ipython2.7 binary installed so i am running it instead of ipython.

Answer (score 9):

This works for me perfectly:

```
pip install jupyter
```