# Unreadable Notebook - Unsupported nbformat version 4 on windows

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I finally was able to install ipython on my Windows 7 PC and it runs without any errors. The problem is that I used to code in ipython but in MAC. Now that I am trying to upload my previous notebooks I receive the following error:

```
Unreadable Notebook: MyFile.ipynb  Unsupported nbformat version 4
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27595587/2827771) for my question but unfortunately that is not for windows and did not resolve my problem. It is worth to mention:

```
ipython --version
```

produces:
    2.3.1

Any help or comment on this is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: And updating `ipython` to the latest version is not an option for you?

Comment: I actually did that using pip but it says "Requirement already up-to-date: ipython in c:\python27\lib\site-packages\ipython-4.0.0-py2.7.egg"

Comment: which means, that you have multiple python versions, and the `ipython` command points to `ipython` from a different installation.

Comment: Interesting. I just removed the other version of python (3.4) and when I do "ipython" it shows me this: Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:16:31) - Not sure why its still using the 3.4 while the only python I have right now is python 2.7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out but I got the first lead from user "cel". I used to have multiple versions of python (2.7 and 3.4). I removed python 3.4 because it's not compatible with spark yet. Next, I had to remove WinPython3.4 and replace it with WinPython2.7 so it can integrate with python 2.7 installed on my PC. Finally, I installed python 2.7.9 and set the `C:/Python27/Script` as a part of system environment variable. After doing all this I ran the following commands:

```
pip uninstall ipython
```

This helped me to remove older version of ipython. Then:

```
pip install ipython
```

This installed the latest version of ipython on my windows pc. Finally:

```
pip install notebook --upgrade
```

To upgrade notebook to latest version. Right now, ipython os installed and and should work fine doing this:

```
ipython notebook
```

Had no problem importing my previous .ipynb after all of the above.

Good luck to you all.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem on Linux. Simply doing:

```
sudo pip install notebook --upgrade
```

worked for me. I have python 3.4 and 2.7 and unlike the answer by nimafl, there was no need for me to remove one them or to first uninstall ipython. A simple upgrade did the trick. Now instead of version 2.3.1 I have version 4.0.3 of ipython.

Comment: Notice that you are talking about Linux which is completely a different story. The same thing happened to me on Unix and as you have mentioned upgrading the notebook solved my problem as well.