# ValueError: Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, nbformat

I was trying to print a plotly plot in Visual Studio Code and caught this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-e07b5feb5ded> in <module>
     30 
     31 fig.update_layout(height=nrows*500)
---> 32 fig.show()

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\plotly\basedatatypes.py in show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3147         import plotly.io as pio
   3148 
-> 3149         return pio.show(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3150 
   3151     def to_json(self, *args, **kwargs):

C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_renderers.py in show(fig, renderer, validate, **kwargs)
    383 
    384         if not nbformat or LooseVersion(nbformat.__version__) < LooseVersion("4.2.0"):
--> 385             raise ValueError(
    386                 "Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed"
    387             )

ValueError: Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed
```

The code I used:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.express as px

df = df[df['Data']>0]
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df = df[(df['Id'] ==1)|(df['Id'] ==6)]

dfp = pd.pivot_table(df,
                     values='Data',
                     index=['Timestamp'],
                     columns=['Id'],
               )
nrows = len(dfp.columns) 

fig = make_subplots(rows=nrows,
                    cols=1,
                    subplot_titles=['Id '+str(c) for c in dfp.columns])

# add traces
x = 1
for i, col in enumerate(dfp.columns):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dfp.index, y=dfp[col].values,
                             name = 'Id '+str(col),
                             mode = 'lines',
                             ),
                  row=i+1,
                  col=1)

fig.update_layout(height=nrows*500)
fig.show()
```

I tried `pip install nbformat` in the console following [this feed on GitHub](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2159#issuecomment-584295704) and [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32336992/11901732)
but it did not work.

However, it seems the code could run with the last 2 rows removed:

```
fig.update_layout(height=nrows*500)
fig.show()
```

Comment: I realised that after restarting VSC the code would work, but thanks for the answer @J00N

Comment: I came here with similar issue on Jupyter python notebook. Kernel -> Restart picked up the new installation too

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**Method 1**

reinstall  ipykernel via

```
pip install ipykernel
```

**Method 2**

```
pip install --upgrade nbformat
```

Comment: or use: conda install -c conda-forge nbformat

Comment: And restart your kernel, extremely important.

Comment: or restart vscode if you are using jupyter directly from vscode (which restarts your vscode's kernel) :-)

Answer (score 66):

```
!pip install nbformat
```

1. Install this.
2. Restart your Kernel.
3. Dam sure it will work!

Comment: Stressing point 2 :-)

Comment: damn sure it did!

Answer (score 7):

For those that use conda, this worked for me:

Verify the name of your conda environment:
`conda info --envs`

Supposing it's "myenv", proceed:

`conda activate myenv`
`conda install nbformat`

Then restart the kernel.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this problem too. In my case, it turned out I had only installed `ipykernel`, but it's best to install the `jupyter` metapackage.

Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks

Comment: does jupyter include nbformat as a dependency? i think this is assumed by your answer but just wanted to double check.

Comment: This solution worked for me, the `nbformat` or `ipykernel` tips did not help.

Comment: `pip install jupyter` is all I needed. Saviour!

Answer (score 2):

**Configurations**

> - Mac OS
> - VS code
> - python 3.x

**Method**

> - Enter the following code:
>   `pip3 install --upgrade nbformat`
> - Restart the kernel in the VS code prompt
> - Run your code again

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

run below command

step 1: write in the box

```
!pip install nbformat
```

step 2: restart the kernel

wooo, your issue is fixed!!!

Comment: This is a duplicate of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69952185/2648551. Please read other answers carefully before posting something.

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/69952185/5025116

Answer (score 0):

if your jupyter notebook is being managed by conda, install nbformat with;

```
conda install -c conda-forge nbformat
```

then restart your kernel.

else use the pip package manager to install or upgrade your nbformat

```
pip install --upgrade nbformat
```

don't forget to restart the kernel as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install jupyter
```

This worked for me but none of the others.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting ipykernel works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34011837)