# Plotly: No renderer could be found for mimetype "application/vnd.plotly.v1+json"

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, nbformat

**Environment:**

- Visual Code
- Jupyter extension (v2022.9.1202862440)
- Kernel: Python 3.10.1 64-bit
- Pyplot version: 5.10.0
- Nbformat version: 5.7.0

**What happened?**

I am trying to use simple boxplot with `plotly.express` via this code:

```
#Basic vizualization
fig = px.box(dataset, y='Rh2')
fig.update_layout(
    height=1000
)
```

First error was pretty straight forward: `ValueError: Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed` which I resolved using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66557572/11101156).

**Second error is the one I am getting now:**

```
No renderer could be found for mimetype "application/vnd.plotly.v1+json", but one might be available on the Marketplace.
```

I have no idea what could be done here - on the internet no such question is mentioned (at least I couldn't find any) + market space didn't help either!

Thanks in advance

---

### EDIT:

Tried adding: `pio.renderers.default = "vscode"` and various others but they result in no error and just blank space.

Comment: "pio.renderers.default = "vscode"" worked for me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to install **Jupyter Notebook Renderers** [extension on vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers).

Comment: Also I installed this extension.