# Plotly Figure not Working: NBformat installing problem

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly

I'm starting to adventure into Plotly library.
I created, in VSCode, a simple figure to start analyzing, as follows:

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig=go.Figure(
    data=[go.Bar(x=[1,2,3],y=[1,2,3])],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title=go.layout.Title(text='A figure specified by a graph object')
    )
)
```

after applying `fig.show()` terminal shows the following error:
ValueError: Mime type rendering requires nbformat>=4.2.0 but it is not installed

I have already installed nbformat in Anaconta Prompt and update it as well, but I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: Try to upgrade it like: pip install nbformat --upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution is pretty straightforward.

```
pip install --upgrade nbformat
```

or

```
!pip install nbformat
```

or something along those lines of resetting the kernel. Others have encountered this problem before. Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66557543/valueerror-mime-type-rendering-requires-nbformat-4-2-0-but-it-is-not-installed)